# Як правильно українською "гето" чи "гетто"?

Tags: правопис, іншомовні-слова, подвоєння

У [чинному правописі](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=86-89) подається шерег винятків іншомовного походження з подвоєнням:

> Тільки в окремих загальних назвах зберігається подвоєння приголосних:
>   анна́ли, бо́нна, бру́тто, ва́нна (ва́нний), мадо́нна, ма́нна
>   (ма́нний), мо́тто, не́тто, па́нна, пе́нні, то́нна, білль, бу́лла,
>   ві́лла, мулла́, ду́рра, мі́рра.

Чому всі пишуть "*гетто*"? 
Це не повний перелік винятків?

P.S. [Тут](http://www.ridnamova.kiev.ua/html/2.11.html) знайшов винятки з "*гетто*". Але питання досі відкрите.

Comment: Думаю що правопис не має такого завдання - перелічити всі слова-винятки. Для цього є орфографічні словники. Запозичення слів відбувається постійно, за цим слідкують словники. Правопис лише вказує що винятки можливі, але для певних слів.

Comment: Дякую, пошукаю словники

Comment: @Oleg СУМ [ГЕ́ТТО, невідм., сер.](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghetto)

Comment: Тлумачний словник української мови у 20-ти томах ГЕ́ТО http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18225&page=618


.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, той СУМ був виданий, ще за старим правописом

Comment: Треба використовувати саме орфографічні словники. У тлумачних словниках більш м'який підхід до орфографії: можуть подавати застарілі слова, або лише один з варіантів написання нового слова, або навести більш сучасний варіант в той час коли орфографічний словник вкаже більш консервативний.

Comment: «Орфоепічний словник», М. І. Погрібний, 1984, дає _гетто_ [гéт:о], «Українська літературна вимова і наголос» під ред. М. А. Жовтобрюха, 1973, дає _гетто_ [гéто].

Comment: Словник словозміни http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/ також має "ге́тто". Словник.уа має ["гето"](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%C3%C5%D2%CE&x=42&y=16).

Comment: @Yellow Sky, тобто затверджують правопис, а ми після того ще сорок років будемо посилатися на старі словники? А якого біса тоді піднімати галас навколо правопису?

Comment: В мене є серйозні сумніви в адекватності нового правопису та в компетентності тих, хто складає словники за ним. А взагалі, якщо ви не помітили, то я тим своїм коментом показав, що не те що т/тт  викликає питання, а й навіть довгота [т] в транскрипції різна в різних словниках.

Comment: @Oleg (Офтоп) не думаю, що в даному контексті можна вживати слово "шерег". Це ж не предмети, розташовані на одній лінії в просторі:  http://sum.in.ua/s/sherengha

Comment: @Idolon, Гадаєте?

"Він зростав як майстер поетичної прози, поступово входячи в шерег найвидатніших радянських прозаїків. "

"Ще нам потребуватиметься натерти немало мозолів, аби побачили в світі ці імена, аби місце достойне в шерегах письменництва поряд зі славетними інших держав знайшли..."

 "Звісно, список усіх можливих ознак, які відкидає “проста” мова, скомпонувати годі. Та все ж можна було б спробувати, наприклад, виділити шерег мовних ознак, присутніх у грамотах приватного або реґіонального характеру..."

Хоча я не фахівець, можу й помилятися.

Comment: @Oleg Перші два приклади відповідають визначенню з СУМ п.2: `Група людей, об'єднаних спільністю інтересів, спільною діяльністю, метою і т. ін.`. Третій - з перекладу, і якраз тут вжитий як синонім до слова `перелік`, тобто так само як у Вашому запитанні. У словниках я даного синоніму знайти не зміг. Думаю, це може бути новим цікавим запитанням для спільноти ;)

Comment: @Oleg - Туди найкраще пасує «низка».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не знаю, як правильно. Пропоную зібрати джерела за різні варіанти. Порядок сортування — з найновіших до старіших.

За «**ге́то**»:

- [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах (том III, відставання – ґуральня, 2012)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18225&page=618).
- [«Великий орфографічний словник сучасної української мови»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Mezhenko_Yurii/Velykyi_orfohrafichnyi_slovnyk_suchasnoi_ukrainskoi_movy/), Юрій Меженко, 2008.
- «Словник-довідник з культури української мови», Д. Гринчишин, А. Капелюшний, О. Сербенська, 2006.

За «**ге́тто**»:

- [«Словники України on-line» від Українського мовно-інформаційний фонду НАН України (2006)](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE) (також [офіційний вхід](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)).
- «Орфоепічний словник», М. І. Погрібний, 1984.
- «Українська літературна вимова і наголос» під ред. М. А. Жовтобрюха, 1973.
- [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах (том II, 1971)](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghetto).
- [«Українсько-англійський словник», К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет, 1955](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE&dicts=8) — в дужках після варіанту на «ґ».
- «Російсько-український словник», гол. ред. М. Я Калинович, М. Ф. Рильский – член редколегії, 1948.

За «**ґе́тто**»:

- [«Українсько-англійський словник», К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет, 1955](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE&dicts=8).

Answer (score 2):

Відповідь на другу частину питання:

> Чому всі пишуть «*гетто*»? Це не повний перелік винятків?

В правописі не сказано, що той перелік повний (хоча й не сказано, що він неповний). В такому випадку нема підстав припускати, що він повний. В такому випадку правопис слова «гет[т]о» регулюють [словники](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1296/4).

Приклади слів, відсутніх в тому переліку, але із беззаперечним подвоєнням: «алло» ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/allo), [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=873&page=37)), «гамма[-проміння]» ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghamma), [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17610&page=592)), «донна» ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/donna), [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23922&page=805)), «канна» ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kanna), [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40324&page=1274)).

Comment: Якщо б автори правопису слово "беладона" не згадали, то як ми мусили б його сьогодні писати, з огляду на те що у словниках трапляються обидві відміни?

Comment: @Oleg, словники не всі рівноважливі. Є більш авторитетні, є менш авторитетні. Я не дуже на цьому знаюся, але, мабуть, мало б питатися так, як в найсучасніших словниках, виданих під егідою НАНУ (ну, за винятком очевидних одруків і помилок).

Comment: [Орфографічний словник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) (або правопи́сний) — словник, що містить перелік слів у їх нормативному написанні та розкриває слова лише в аспекті їх правопису. Орфографічний словник є показником сучасного йому правопису. Різновиди: загальні.., шкільні.., галузеві, словники-довідники для працівників друкарства — містять складні випадки, а також докладне викладення правописних норм та відомостей, необхідних для коректорської та редакторської роботи.

Comment: @Artemix, не зовсім зрозумів суть коментаря. Ви маєте на увазі, що про написання слова не варто судити за тлумачним словником? Чи просто що орфографічний має пріоритет над іншими? (Чи ні те, ні інше?)

Comment: @Sasha Це цитата з вікіпедії яка підкреслює зв'язок саме орфографічного словника із правописом. Тобто зміни у правописі призводять до змін у словнику. Є спеціалізовані (професійні) словники саме для використання коректорами. Саме ці словники є авторитетом у питаннях орфографії.

Comment: Словники - не Святе Письмо, і складаються вони виходячи з тенденцій конкретної мови. А в українській є така тенденція, що подвоєні приголосні - це зазвичай або префікси-суфікси прикладені до кореня (як-от "віддавати", "каяття", "знання"), або була голосна, але довгоносик поїв (напр., "ссавець"), і тому читаються вони як окремі звуки, а не подовжені приголосні. Себто, для іноземних мов треба слухати, як воно звучить в оригіналі, як-от "Аладдін" (ориг. Алa'aд-Дін), чи те ж "tt" в італійській, де воно таки звучить радше як подвійне [t] на відміну від "ss", що позначає довгу "s".