# Правопис 1960 року

Tags: правопис

Підкажіть, будь ласка, де я можу в інтернеті знайти текст останнього радянського українського правопису, це так звана редакція 1960 року. Я його довго шукав, та марно, сучасні всі видання є, харківський є, навіть часів УНР є, а того немає. Він мені потрібен для порівняння з попереднім, 1946 року, та сучасним. Як альтернатива, мені було б досить і просто докладного переліку відмінностей між радянським та сучасним правописами.

Comment: Здається, після 1960 (II) ще був 1990 (III), тобто не останній (хоча можу помилятися). А Ви десь знайшли 1946 (я знайшов лише шматки)? Не знаю, я сам не знайшов ані 1960, ані 1990. [Тут знайдені мною](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/4). [Тут](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/PRAWOPYS/) є деякі книги, що *можуть* містити порівняння, але не дивився.

Comment: @Sasha - 1946 я не знайшов, мене більше цікавить 1960, бо саме ним було видано основну масу книжок українською. Це питання в мене виникло через нещодавнє [инше питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1295/) про _гето/гетто_. Там де-хто збурювався через те, що в коментах цитували застарілий правопис 1960. От мені й цікаво, як у 1960 було сформульовано правило про подвійні приголосні в иншомовних словах, бо тоді ж писали _комунізм_ таки з однією <м>, а _гетто_ з двома <т>, а зараз сучасні словники пишуть його з одним <т>. Просто дуже хочеться глянути, як у 1960 було сформульовано.

Answer (score 7):

Давно вже є в переліку правописіⷪв на [метіⷷ](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/585). Ось окремою [ланкою](//archive.org/details/up-1960).

---

<sup>Стара віⷪдповіⷷдь.</sup>

Частини, огляди чи поріⷪвняння.

- [Часопис](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81_(%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB)) [„Фенікс“ Зошит 12 (1964)](//diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/15991/file.pdf#page=28) ¬ Український правопис 1960 року (Богдан Сацюк)
- [Часопис](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Ukrainian_Studies) [„Journal of Ukrainian Studies“ Vol. 5 Num. 1 (весна 1980)](//diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/13818/file.pdf#page=17) ¬ Український правопис: [1928](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) vs 1960 [(Андрій Горняткевич)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)
- [<s>Передмова плюс заставка</s>](http://movahistory.org.ua/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1960_%D1%80._%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0.) ¬ [<s>§ 30. Правила переносу</s>](http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/language/ukrainian/ukrhyph/rules60.pdf)¹

---

1. Ланку надав [Andrii Zhuk](/users/254)